# How to generate dynamic query in @Query annotation from spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

My json which stored mongodb,

{

```
  "deviceId": "testdevice",
   "deviceData": {
    "device_owner": "Anand",
    "device_type": "xxxx"
    "device_desc": "xxxx"
     ...

  }
}
```

Here deviceData is device specific.It may vary based on devices. I want to generate dynamic way to filter data based on device data , i.e, deviceData.OBJECT=VALUE. I am trying to retrieve the value from spring boot app.

My spring boot DAO class

@Query({'device':?0, 'deviceData.filterString'})
Page findByDeviceData(String deviceId, String filterString,Pageable pageable);

Can any one help how to achieve this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried to pass query as  parameter , its not working 
@Query(?0) Page findByDeviceData(String queryString,Pageable pageable);